# Why does my compiler percieve a string to be a const char[]?

Tags: c++, string, oop

Constructor

```
PixelPlane::PixelPlane(int& width, int& height, const std::string& label)
```

Whenever I initialize the object with the following arguments

```
PixelPlane pixel_plane(960, 540, "Title");
```

Visual Studio underlines the `960` argument and displays the message `No instance of constructor "PixelPlane::PixelPlane matches the argument list. Argument types are: (int, int, const char[5])`. I saw someone do something similar without errors https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nfuYMXjZsA. Have I done something wrong or have I just overlooked something?

Comment: The problem isn't the string, it's the `int`s. You can't pass an `int` literal to a function that takes a `int&`.

Comment: To answer the title, a string literal is an array of constant characters (in C++). The compiler is correct. (In C, the elements do not have the `const` attribute but are practically constant because the behavior upon attempting to modify them is not defined by the standard.)

Comment: @FredLarson Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Why are you passing them by reference? If you're intending to modify them, you can't do that to literals. If you're not, you don't need to pass them by reference.

Comment: Minor point: I think you mistyped the error message. The type of `"Title"` is `const char[6]`, not `const char[5]`. There's an implied `'\0'` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing [*rvalue*s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues) (960 and 540) as an argument to the constructor that takes `int&` references. This is forbidden. The only time you can bind a rvalue to a reference is when the reference is marked `const`, e.g. `const int&` (or when you have a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references); see also Scott Meyers' [excellent post](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (just replace *universal* by *forwarding*, as that's how those references are now called in the C++ standard)).

`std::string` has [an implicit conversion from `const char*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (ctor #5 in the link), to which the `const char[5]` type of `label` decays to, so the string part is OK.

BTW, do not pass fundamental types by `const` reference. It doesn't save anything, and may prevent optimization. Pass by `const` reference only when the objects to be passed are expensive to copy (or when you deal with template code, see @Mark's comment). In your case just pass them by value

```
PixelPlane::PixelPlane(int width, int height, const std::string& label)
```

Comment: It's OK to pass by const reference if it's a template function and you don't know if making a copy will be expensive or not.

Comment: @MarkRansom True

Answer (score 3):

This

```
PixelPlane::PixelPlane(int& width, int& height, const std::string& label)
```

is trying to say: "Pass me a reference to two integers, because I want to modify them"

Informally speaking, you cannot modify `960` or `540`. That doesnt make sense. And because it doesnt make sense the language forbids you do pass `960` or `540` where a (non-const) reference is expected.

More formally, `960` and `540` are rvalues. They dont have names, they cannot be assigned to.

Solution: change the constructor to take `const int&` or even better just `int` (assuming the parameters are not modified).

> Why does my compiler percieve a string to be a const char[]?

String literals arent `std::string`s. `"Title"` really is a `const char[5]` (see eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, do you have a source stating that string literals are const arrays? Everything I've seen so far says they're `const char *`, though experience has shown me it's an array.

Comment: @Chipster added a link. "The type of an unprefixed string literal is const char[N]"

Comment: @Chipster seems like everything you have seen so far was wrong ;) arrays are not pointers. However typically you write `const char * my_string = "Hello world"` because array can decay to pointers

Comment: Oh, I'm sure everything I've seen so far is wrong. It'd just be nice to see the right thing once in a while ;). I had already up-voted your answer anyway, because it was a good answer even without the link, but thanks for the link.

Comment: @Chipster didnt want to come across as arrogant. Actually I am at a complete loss when the topic is c-arrays, string literals being `const char[N]` is about everything I know for sure

Comment: @Chipster then nevermind, its just too easy to misunderstand or be misunderstood

Comment: A fun thing when arrays stay arrays (passing them by array reference): `template <class T, size_t N> void f(T (&arr)[N]){std::cout << "I'm an array of " << N << " elements\n";}`, see [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99d8fb44fb4355a3).